# Parsing JSON to a regular JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How can I load a regular array from a JSON Response like this:

```
{"project":"8","powerline":"188.396496","road":"7.876766","cost":"69885005.45"}
```

to

```
var cars = [8, 188.396496, 7.876766, 69885005.45];
```

I already tried something like this:

```
req.done(function(data) {
var cars = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

but it is not doing the job.

Comment: Hi kamesh it is jquery json object

Comment: I believe the OP has forgotten to add node.js as a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply run a `for..in` loop like this. and keep pushing the values into a new array.

```
var obj = {
    "project" : "8",
    "powerline" : "188.396496",
    "road" : "7.876766",
    "cost" : "69885005.45"
}

var arr = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    var val = parseFloat("0" + obj[key]);
    arr.push(val)
}
```

Comment: Hi rajub, thanks for reply but as I already mentioned I am getting the JSON from a Ajax request so how I can use your approach?

Comment: You want to fetch array instead of JSON from ajax? then will have to do on server side

Comment: besides, it is loading the keys as STRING into the array. Is there any way to force them be populate as Numbers like 8 instead of "8"

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate JSON object as Array, please try this way

```
req.done(function(data) {
 var cars = $.map(JSON.parse(data), function(value, index){
   return i;
});
 console.log(cars);
});
```

Comment: Hi Girish, Thanks for reply but this is not functioning,

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're getting an object when you're calling `JSON.parse`. You can run the following to get the values without keys:

```
req.done(function (data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data),
        cars = []

    for (var key in jsonData) {
        cars.push(jsonData[key])
    }
})
```